# How to return true when any odd bit of x equals 1; false otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

The function for returning True or False depending at the last binary number:

```py
def any_odd(x):
    x = str(bin(x))
    return True if x[-1] == 1 else False
```

The result in the output always returns only 'False' I tried looking for the solution, but I still could not find it.

Comment: `'1' == 1` is always `False`. Change the comparison to `x[-1] == "1"`

Comment: your title and description don't match. Do you need to test "any odd bits", as in `1010` or only the last bit? For the latter, just use `x & 1`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing string to a number. Change the `return` to

```py
return True if x[-1] == "1" else False
```

or even better

```py
return x[-1] == "1"
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

> *"how to Return true when any odd bit of x equals 1; false otherwise ..."*

A quick way is to just traverse the provided bits, comparing each odd indice.
Note, I'm using a *[slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)* here, since the *[bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin)* function will return the value with a *"0b"* prefix.

```py
x = 123
b = False
for i, x in enumerate(bin(x)[2:]):
    if i % 2 and x == '1':
        b = True
        break
```

Alternately, for comparison, use the *[bit-wise](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)*, and *[bit-shift](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations)* operators.

```java
x = 123
b = False
for i in reversed(range(len(str(x)))):
    if i % 2 and x & (1 << i):
        b = True
        break
```

Ideally though, you may want to create an index.  For example, multiples of *4*, or *8*.
You can utilize a mathematical *[ceil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* operation to derive the next multiple.

```py
import math
n = len(s := str(bin(123))[2:])
N = math.ceil(n / 8.) * 8
for i, x in enumerate(('0' * (N - n)) + s):
    if i % 2 and x == '1':
        b = True
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to return true when any odd bit of x equals 1; false otherwise

Doesn't agree with:

> The function for returning True or False depending at the last
> binary number:

Which is simply:

```
def final_on(x):
    return bool(x & 1)
```

without the `bin()` and `str` stuff.  As far as are there any *on* bits, we can do:

```
def any_on(x):
    return x != 0
```

as every number will have odd (1) bits in it unless it's 0.  If we want to check only *odd* bit positions for an *on* bit, using `bin()` we can do:

```
def any_odd_on(x):
    return any(z == '1' for z in bin(x)[-1:1:-2])
```

Though we could probably do it more efficiently arithmetically and avoid the `str` conversion.  If this doesn't solve it, perhaps you explain in more detail what you want.